# Shifting edit text hints with android studio

Tags: android, android-edittext, hint

Does anyone know how to shift `EditText` hints a little bit on the right so my drawables on the left of the hint don't stand so sticky?

I tried with gravity attribute but it seems that that's not the good way to do it. I am thinking about to nest an imageView + an editText in a container for every input of my formula but it seems a bit dirty, isn't it?

[Here you can see what I am talking about](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OEo8s.png)

Comment: Back in the 'olden days' we used to use logic to build our own hints for text boxes. It is a bit more complex than using the API to do it for you, but it gives you a bit more freedom in situations like yours. Not to mention, the result will be a little less cut-n-paste than the alternative. That said, your best option is probably to use the space trick that @Zain is suggesting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `drawablePadding` property:

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:drawableStart="@android:drawable/star_big_on"
    android:drawablePadding="10dp"
    android:hint="Username"/>
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There is a simple trick you can do by prepending spaces to the hint text..

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_baseline_account_circle_24"
    android:hint="   Username" />
```

[image]

Comment: The problem can be input text. When a user starts writing sth to EditText hint will disappear and text will be next to drawable.

Comment: @iknow absolutely right but not sure if the poster wants to shift the typed-in text as well, they just asked about the hint

Comment: Yeah, if @floMartin wants only to shift hint Your answer is correct and clever :D

Comment: @iknow your answer is perfect though for both ;)